# converting an ftable to a matrix

Tags: r, matrix

Take for example the following ftable

```
height <- c(rep('short', 7), rep('tall', 3))
girth <- c(rep('narrow', 4), rep('wide', 6))
measurement <- rnorm(10)
foo <- data.frame(height=height, girth=girth, measurement=measurement)
ftable.result <- ftable(foo$height, foo$girth)
```

I'd like to convert the above `ftable.result` into a matrix with row names and column names.  Is there an efficient way of doing this?  `as.matrix()` doesn't exactly work, since it won't attach the row names and column names for you.

You could do the following

```
ftable.matrix <- ftable.result
class(ftable.matrix) <- 'matrix'

rownames(ftable.matrix) <- unlist(attr(ftable.result, 'row.vars'))
colnames(ftable.matrix) <- unlist(attr(ftable.result, 'col.vars'))
```

However, it seems a bit heavy-handed.   Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [2 solutions on R-Help](http://n4.nabble.com/converting-a-table-to-a-dataframe-or-a-matrix-td856133.html#a856133):

```
head(as.table(ftable.result), Inf)
```

Or

```
t <- as.table(ftable.result)
class(t) <- "matrix"
```

Comment: I didn't know that you could use `as.table` in that fashion.

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that @Shane had originally posted (but quickly deleted) what *is* a correct answer with more recent versions of R.

Somewhere along the way, an `as.matrix` method was added for `ftable` (I haven't found it in the NEWS files I read through though.

The `as.matrix` method for `ftable` lets you deal fairly nicely with "nested" frequency tables (which is what `ftable` creates quite nicely). Consider the following:

```
temp <- read.ftable(textConnection("breathless yes no
coughed yes no
age
20-24  9  7  95 1841
25-29 23  9 108 1654
30-34 54 19 177 1863"))

class(temp)
# [1] "ftable"
```

The `head(as.table(...), Inf)` trick doesn't work with such `ftables` because `as.table` would convert the result into a multi-dimensional array.

```
head(as.table(temp), Inf)
#  [1]    9   23   54   95  108  177    7    9   19 1841 1654 1863
```

For the same reason, the second suggestion also doesn't work:

```
t <- as.table(temp)
class(t) <- "matrix"
# Error in class(t) <- "matrix" : 
#   invalid to set the class to matrix unless the dimension attribute is of length 2 (was 3)
```

---

However, with more recent versions of R, simply using `as.matrix` would be fine:

```
as.matrix(temp)
#        breathless_coughed
# age     yes_yes yes_no no_yes no_no
#   20-24       9      7     95  1841
#   25-29      23      9    108  1654
#   30-34      54     19    177  1863

class(.Last.value)
# [1] "matrix"
```

---

If you prefer a `data.frame` to a `matrix`, check out `table2df` from my ["mrdwabmisc" package on GitHub](https://github.com/mrdwab/mrdwabmisc).